# How is the value of 'this' different in concrete implementation than on playground?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, this

I am developing an app using a Node-Express stack using Socket.io and I found something weird. I have the following in one of my files:

```
const server = require('./server')
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
const Game = require('./service/game')
const game = new Game()

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  
  ...
  
  game.addPlayer(socket)

  socket.on('increaseTime', game.increaseTime) // I know this is wrong
})
```

I have read about how you have to bind this if you want to use a callback as a handler, so in this specific case I know that on the commented line one of the solutions is the following to actually bind 'this' to the game instance, instead of the socket:

```
socket.on('increaseTime', game.increaseTime.bind(game))
```

What I do not understand is not this issue, but related to this. If I leave the line as is, so in the 'wrong' version I would still like to know how is the value of 'this' the socket. That is not what I would expect, because if I try to simulate this in a playground file, the value of this would be the the global object:

```
const socket = {
  on(label, callback) {
    callback()
  },
}

const game = {
  increaseTime() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

socket.on('increaseTime', game.increaseTime) // global object
```

My guess is that the reason that it is the global object is that the value of this is lost, because when we use the 'this' keyword in a function inside of another function, it loses it's value and falls back to the global object (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/). My main question is how is it possible that the value of 'this' is the socket if I leave the 'wrong' implementation, how is it not the same as in the playground file?

I also tried instantiating dummy classes to have something resembling the actual implementation, but then the value of 'this' would be undefined, which I do not understand either (maybe it could be that the class keyword uses strict mode implicitely, so the fallback is not the global object, I don't know).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What? No you don't. Just give a real function as callback: `socket.on('increaseTime', function(data) { game.increaseTime(); })`, or with an arrow function: `socket.on("...", data => game.increaseTime())`. The problem isn't really the fact that "this" is the wrong thing (that's only the symptom), but that you need to pass a proper callback. By passing `game.increaseTime` you're passing a reference to a _prototype's_ function.

Comment: Your fake `socket` doesn't call `callback` in the same way as a real socket `EventEmitter` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on how the function is called.

`game.increaseTime.bind(game)` creates a function which calls `increaseTime` with `game` as the `this` value.

`callback()` calls the function passed to the `callback` argument (and copied from `game`) without any explicit context (so `this` is the global object).

The code underlying `socket.on` clearly calls the function passed to it with the socket as the `this` value. There are several ways it *could* do that, you'd need to look at its source code to determine which one it uses.

Comment: The most helpful line was 'callback() calls the function passed to the callback argument (and copied from game) without any explicit context (so this is the global object).'

This made me realize that when finding out the value of the 'this' keyword, what matters is 'how' the callback (the function that actually contains the 'this' keyword was called). It's not

- where the higher order function was called
- in which context the higher order function was called
- where the callback function was called

but in which context the callback function was called.